# Are futures a safe way to check for individual thread completion?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, thread-safety

I've been toying around with Boost's futures and was wondering if they were an acceptable and safe way to check if an individual thread has completed.

I had never used them before so most of the code I wrote was based off of [Boost's Synchronization documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/future.hpp>

int calculate_the_answer_to_life_the_universe_and_everything()
{
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
    return 42;
}

int main()
{
    boost::packaged_task<int> task(calculate_the_answer_to_life_the_universe_and_everything);
    boost::unique_future<int> f(task.get_future());

    boost::thread th(boost::move(task));

    while(!f.is_ready())
    {
        std::cout << "waiting!" << std::endl;
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
    }

    std::cout << f.get() << std::endl;

    th.join();
}
```

This appears to wait for the calculate_the_answer_to_life_the_universe_and_everything() thread to return 42. Could something possibly go wrong with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you can check whether the future's result is ready. The thread that produces the result doesn't necessarily have to have terminated, I suppose.

Comment: Certainly, busy-waiting with a sleep is not the right thing to do. You probably wrote this as demo-code, though.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, futures are safe to use in that way, and the code is (at a quick glance) safe and correct.

There are other ways to do the same thing (e.g. using an `atomic_flag`, or mutex-protected data, or many others) but your code is a valid way to do it.

N.B. instead of `f.is_ready()` and `this_thread::sleep(seconds(1))` you could use `f.wait_for(seconds(1))`, which would wake as soon as the result is made ready.  That waits directly on the future, instead of checking the future, then waiting using a separate mechanism, then checking, then waiting with a separate mechanism etc.

And instead of `packaged_task` and `thread` you could use `async`.

Using C++11 names instead of boost ...

```
int main()
{
    auto f =  std::async(std::launch::async, calculate_the_answer_to_life_the_universe_and_everything);

    while(f.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)) == std::future_status::timeout)
        std::cout << "waiting!" << std::endl;

    std::cout << f.get() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I've been toying around with Boost's futures and was wondering if they were an acceptable and safe way to check if an individual thread has completed.

Futures are a mechanism for asynchronous evaluation, not a synchronization mechanism. Although some of the primitives do have synchronization properties (`future<>::get`), the library is not designed to *synchronize*, but rather to fire a task and ignore it until the result is needed.

Comment: I disagree, futures are designed to synchronize. Running a task in another thread is easy, safely synchronising the provider of a result with an execution agent waiting for that result is harder, and an important part of the futures library.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I might not have been clear enough. The goal of the library is not synchronization but asynchronous execution of tasks. The asynchronous execution of tasks *requires* synchronization (to read the result), but futures were not designed *to synchronize*. While you can abuse futures for that for example by creating a `future<bool>` where the value will be set when the thread completes, and that is a use case whose sole purpose is synchronization, `future` is not the best tool for that.

Comment: It depends what you mean by "the library" and "futures". `std::future` and `std::shared_future` are designed to synchronise (but `future<void>` does a better job than `future<bool>` for simply knowing if something completed.) `std::async` is designed to execute tasks.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: If you think that `future<>` is *the* tool to use to check whether a thread has completed, then we don't agree, but you are very welcome to add an answer to that respect. I might be wrong (I have been multiple times in the past, and I will surely be wrong in the future again)

Comment: It's certainly not _the_ tool, condition variables or simply a flag (either atomic or protected by a mutex) work fine too, but futures are  another option.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Rereading the text I am thinking that I have not been clear when I said *the goal of the library [is] asynchronous execution of tasks*. The `future`s library is a communication mechanism that supports the asynchronous execution, *not* a mechanism for that execution.

Comment: Yes, I think that was the crux of my objection, I agree now :)

Comment: Thanks for the interesting read guys. Just a followup, what would the more _correct_ way be to check if one or many threads (but not all) had completed a task?

Comment: @noko If you have *tasks*, then checking the futures (*and* joining afterwards) is the way to go, but that is a completely different question than *knowing when a thread has completed*. That is, if you communication protocol with the threads are futures, they do support all you need. But you should not *force* the use of `future`s just to *know if a thread has completed*.